# C++ pointer array argument

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arguments

I have the following code:

```
void getPossibilities(int *rating[200][3]){
// do something
}

int main ()
{
int rating[200][3];
getPossibilities(&rating);
}
```

this throws following error message:

> error: cannot convert int (*)[200][3] to int (*)[3] for argument 1 to void getPossibilities(int (*)[3])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing an array of N-dimensions to a function, the 0th dimension is always ignored. That's why `a[N]` decays to `*p`. In the same way, `a[N][M]` decays to `(*p)[M]`.
Here, `(*p)[M]` is a pointer to an array of `M` elements.

```
int a1[N][M], a2[M];
int (*p)[M];
p = a1; // array a1[N][M] decays to a pointer
p = &a2; // p is a pointer to int[M]
```

So your function signature should be:

```
void getPossibilities(int (*rating)[3]);
```

Now since you are using, C++, it's worth taking advantage of its facility where you can pass an array by reference. So preferred way is:

```
void getPossibilities(int (&rating)[200][3]);
```

Answer (score 5):

The function signature should be this:

```
void getPossibilities(int (*rating)[3]);
```

and pass argument as:

```
getPossibilities(rating);
```

The variable `rating` is a two dimentional array of form `T[M][N]` which can decay into a type which is of form `T(*)[N]`. So I think that is all you want.

As in the above solution the array decays, losing the size of one dimension (in the function you only know `N` reliably, you just loss `M` due to the array-decay), so you've to change the signature of the function to avoid decaying of the array:

```
void getPossibilities(int (&rating)[200][3]) //note : &, 200, 3
{
  //your code
}

//pass argument as before
getPossibilities(rating);  //same as above
```

Better yet is to use template as:

```
 template<size_t M, size_t N>
 void getPossibilities(int (&rating)[M][N])
 {
       //you can use M and N here
       //for example
       for(size_t i = 0 ; i < M ; ++i)
       {
          for(size_t j = 0 ; j < N ; ++j)
          {
             //use rating[i][j]
          }    
       }
 }
```

To use this function, you've to pass the argument as before:

```
 getPossibilities(rating); //same as before!
```

Comment: but I need a two dimensional array, in my function I use something like this:

\*rating[i][0] = \*rating[i][0] +1;

then the error is error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Comment: The function signature should be strongly typed.

Comment: @DeadMG: Isn't it strongly-typed?

Comment: @Nawaz My problem now is that if I parse _rating_ without the \*, that the value is not changed when the function is finished, or is it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between [`int (*x)[200][3]`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%20%28%2ax%29%5B200%5D%5B3%5D) and [`int *x[200][3]`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%20%2ax%5B200%5D%5B3%5D)